# How do I prevent duplication of my root xml during my for loop

Tags: xml, for-loop, xquery, dtd, basex

```
for $i in doc(test.xml)//hosptial

return file:append(filepath\dirTest.xml,
    <studentID>
        <hospitalName>
            <ambo>{$i//ambo}</ambo>
        </hospitalName>
    <studentID>
)
```

my file executes successfully but because test.xml has multiple hospitals when it loops it recreates my studentID and makes my xml not wellformed

Comment: It might help us the clarify the problem if you show us both the input structure of test.xml as well as the result structure of the XML you want to create. Also, if you use `file:append` does that mean you want to add contents to an existing file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have one root element `studentID` and potentially several `hospitalName` in it.  So you need to take the root element out of the loop and simply embed the loop "inside" it:

```
<studentID> {
  for $i in doc(test.xml)//hosptial
  return
    <hospitalName>
      <ambo>{$i//ambo}</ambo>
    </hospitalName>
}
<studentID>
```

I removed the call to `file:append`, which I am not sure to understand here.  But the above code would give you the element I think you want.